# How to do Addition inside a addClick function

Tags: reactjs

Please help me out what to do here to make addition of two numbers. When I click on addClick function, it is not making addition.
when I type 2 and 2, it is showing 22 not 4.
please help me out what to do here.
I am new here.

**App.jsx:**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App(){

  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState('');
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState('');
  const [headingText, setHeading] = useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {
    setNumber1(event.target.value);
    setNumber2(event.target.value);

  }

  function addClick(event){
    let sum;
    sum = number1 + number2;
    setHeading(sum);
    event.preventDefault();
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="number1">Number1</label>
        <input onChange={handleChange} type="number"/>
        <label htmlFor="number2">Number2</label>
        <input onChange={handleChange} type="number"/>
        <button onClick={addClick} type="submit">Add</button>
        <button type="submit">Subtract</button>
        <button type="submit">Multiplication</button>
        <button type="submit">Division</button>
        <h1>Result: {headingText}</h1>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the statements:

```
setNumber1(event.target.value);
setNumber2(event.target.value);

with 

setNumber1(parseInt(event.target.value));
setNumber2(parseInt(event.target.value));

OR

setNumber1(event.target.valueAsNumber);
setNumber2(event.target.valueAsNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the input value with Number. With the current structure, it is difficult to get the desired result because your input values ​​change at the same time.
When you type in Number1, Number1 and Number2 are changed at the same time.

```
  function handleChange(event) {
    setNumber1(event.target.value);
    setNumber2(event.target.value);
  }

<input onChange={handleChange} type="number"/>
<input onChange={handleChange} type="number"/>
```

change

```
  function handleChange1(event) {
    setNumber1(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  }

  function handleChange2(event) {
    setNumber2(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  }

  <input onChange={handleChange1} value={number1} type="number"/>
  <input onChange={handleChange2} value={number2} type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative is that you can change the way in which you are defining the number1 in useState.

You can define them like

```
const [number1, setNumber1] = useState(0);
const [number2, setNumber2] = useState(0);
```

Also you are missing `value` in input

```
<input onChange={handleChange} value={number1} type="number"/>
<input onChange={handleChange} value={number2} type="number"/>
```

And simply use the other code as same.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use form here, since you store the values in state, you can just perform the tasks easily like so.

```
<button onClick={addClick}>Add</button>
```